# Unable to load a .h5 keras model

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I trained a multi-class Unet model using keras built-in metrics and loss (Accuracy and categorical_crossentropy). After the end  of the training,  I saved the model with the following command:

```
 model.save('my_model.h5')
```

but when I'm trying to load the model using the following command:

```
 saved_model = keras.models.load_model('mymodel.h5')
```

it raises the following error:

```
    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```

I'm using Tensorflow 1.12 and keras 2.1.6.

The entire error is presented below:

```
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6cafa6e56c85> in <module>
      4 #  saved_model = keras.models.load_model('lunar5.h5', custom_objects={'dice_coef': dice_coef, 'recall': keras_metrics.recall, 'precision': keras_metrics.precision})
      5 #saved_model = keras.models.load_model('model/model_v1.hdf5')
----> 6 saved_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('lunar6.h5')

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    228       raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
    229     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
--> 230     model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    231 
    232     # set weights

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
    308                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
    309   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 310   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    311 
    312 

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     62       module_objects=globs,
     63       custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 64       printable_module_name='layer')

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    171             custom_objects=dict(
    172                 list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 173                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    174       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    175         return cls.from_config(config['config'])

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1290     # First, we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed
   1291     for layer_data in config['layers']:
-> 1292       process_layer(layer_data)
   1293     # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
   1294     # Nodes that cannot yet be processed (if the inbound node

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in process_layer(layer_data)
   1276       from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize as deserialize_layer  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   1277 
-> 1278       layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
   1279       created_layers[layer_name] = layer
   1280 

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     62       module_objects=globs,
     63       custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 64       printable_module_name='layer')

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    173                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    174       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 175         return cls.from_config(config['config'])
    176     else:
    177       # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
   1604         A layer instance.
   1605     """
-> 1606     return cls(**config)
   1607 
   1608 

~/anaconda3/envs/lunar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py in __init__(self, max_value, negative_slope, threshold, **kwargs)
    307   def __init__(self, max_value=None, negative_slope=0, threshold=0, **kwargs):
    308     super(ReLU, self).__init__(**kwargs)
--> 309     if max_value is not None and max_value < 0.:
    310       raise ValueError('max_value of Relu layer '
    311                        'cannot be negative value: ' + str(max_value))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```

Any thoughts ?